# Weak$^*$ convergence of subgradients of a convex continuous function on a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, convex-analysis, weak-convergence

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

---

Let $A$ be a subset of a normed space $X$ and $f:A \to \mathbb R$.

- Let $a \in \operatorname{int} A$. For $v \in X$, the *right directional* derivative $f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$, the *left directional* derivative $f_{-}^{\prime}(a)[v]$, and the (*bilateral*) directional derivative $f^{\prime}(a)[v]$ are defined by:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t} \\
  f_{-}^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0^-} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t} \\
  f^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t}.
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  We say that $f$ is *Gâteaux differentiable* at $a$ if $f^{\prime}(a) \in X^{*}$.
- The *subdifferential* of $f$ at $a \in A$ is the set
  $$
  \partial f(a)=\left\{x^* \in X^* \mid f(x) - f(a) \ge \langle x^*, x-a \rangle \text { for each } x \in A\right\}.
  $$
  The elements of $\partial f(a)$ are called *subgradients* of $f$ at $a$.

> **Theorem:** Assume $A$ is open convex and $f$ convex continuous. If $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $a \in A$, then
> $$
> |x_n - a| \to 0, x_n \in A, x_n^* \in \partial f(x_n) \implies x_n^* \stackrel{w^*}{\to} f'(a).
> $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478569/assume-a-is-open-convex-and-f-convex-continuous-then-f-is-g%c3%a2teaux-differe) result, $\partial f (a) = \{f'(a)\}$ is a singleton. To simplify notation, let $a^* = f'(a)$. Assume the contrary that $x_n^*$ does not converge to $a^*$ in $w^*$-topology, i.e., there is $v \in X$ such that $\langle x^*_n, v \rangle \not\to \langle a^*, v \rangle$. There is $\varepsilon > 0$ (and by extracting a subsequence) such that
$$
| \langle x^*_n - a^*, v \rangle | \ge \varepsilon \quad \forall n.
$$

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457172/does-my-proof-generalize-this-exercise-about-continuity-of-convex-lower-semi-con) result, $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $A$, i.e.,  there are $r, L>0$ such that $B(a, r) \subset A$ and $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz on $B(a, r)$. Then by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478500/assume-a-is-open-convex-and-f-convex-continuous-then-f-is-l-lipschitz-o) result,
$$
\bigcup_{x \in B(a, r)} \partial f (a) \subset L B_{X^*}.
$$

By Banach-Alaoglu theorem (and by extracting a subsequence), there is $x^* \in X^*$ such that $x_n^* \stackrel{w^*}{\to} x^*$. We have for all $x\in A$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) - f(x_n) &\ge \langle x_n^*, x-x_n \rangle \\
&= \langle x_n^*, x-a \rangle + \langle x_n^*, a-x_n \rangle \\
&\ge \langle x_n^*, x-a \rangle +  -\|x_n^*\||a-x_n|.
\end{align}
$$

Notice that $(x_n^*) \subset LB_{X^*}$ is bounded. By taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we have
$$
f(x)-f(a) \ge  \langle x_n^*, x-a \rangle \quad \forall x\in X.
$$

So $x^* \in \partial f (a)$. It follows that $x^* = a^*$ and thus $\langle x^*_n - a^*, v \rangle \to 0$ which is a contradiction.

---

**Update:** @daw has pointed a mistake in above proof. Below is my fix.

By Banach-Alaoglu theorem, there are $x^* \in X^*$ a and a subnet $(x^*_{\varphi(d)})_{d\in D}$ of $(x^*_n)$ such that $x^*_{\varphi (d)} \stackrel{w^*}{\to} x^*$. Here $D$ is a directed set and $\varphi:D \to \mathbb N$ a [monotone cofinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet_(mathematics)#Definitions) map. We have for all $x\in A$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) - f(x_{\varphi (d)}) &\ge \langle x_{\varphi (d)}^*, x-x_{\varphi (d)} \rangle \\
&= \langle x_{\varphi (d)}^*, x-a \rangle + \langle x_{\varphi (d)}^*, a-x_{\varphi (d)} \rangle \\
&\ge \langle x_{\varphi (d)}^*, x-a \rangle   - \| x_{\varphi (d)}^* \||a-x_{\varphi (d)}|.
\end{align}
$$

Now we need the following simple result for net convergence.

> **Lemma:** Let $(x_d)_{d\in D}, (y_d)_{d\in D}$ be nets in $\mathbb R$. Assume $x_d \to 0$ and there is $r$ such that $|y_d| \le r$ for all $d\in D$. Then $x_dy_d \to 0$.
>
> *Proof:* Let $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ be a neighborhood of $0$. Because $x_d \to 0$, there is $d' \in D$ such that $x_d \in (-\varepsilon/r, \varepsilon/r)$ for all $d\in D$ such that $d' \le d$. It follows that $x_dy_d \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ for all $d \in D$ such that $d' \le d$. Hence $x_dy_d \to 0$.

Notice that $(x_{\varphi (d)}^*) \subset LB_{X^*}$ is bounded. By taking the limit and applying the **Lemma**, we have
$$
f(x)-f(a) \ge  \langle x^*, x-a \rangle \quad \forall x\in X.
$$

So $x^* \in \partial f (a)$. It follows that $x^* = a^*$ and thus $\langle x^*_{\varphi(d)} - a^*, v \rangle \to 0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I think going to weak-star converging sub-sequences requires $X$ to be separable.

Comment: @daw I have updated my proof with a fix using net convergence. Could you have a check on my attempt?