# The inverse of the subdifferential of a strictly convex function is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, measurable-functions, hausdorff-distance

Let $X := \mathbb R^d$ and $h: X \to \mathbb R$ be strictly convex. Then

- $\partial h (x)$ [is non-empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477191/continuous-convex-function-on-a-normed-vector-space-has-non-empty-subdifferentia), [convex, and compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478500/assume-a-is-open-convex-and-f-convex-continuous-then-f-is-l-lipschitz-o) for all $x \in X$.
- $\partial h (x) \cap \partial h (y) \neq \emptyset$ [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477191/continuous-convex-function-on-a-normed-vector-space-has-non-empty-subdifferentia) $x=y$.

Let $D := \bigcup_{x\in X} \partial h (x)$. Then the inverse $(\partial h)^{-1} : D \to X$ of $\partial h$ is well-defined. Let $g:=(\partial h)^{-1}$ and $d_H$ be the [Hausdorff distance](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hausdorff_distance#Definition) on the collection of compact subsets of $X$.

For $x, x_n \in X$, if $d_H(\partial h(x_n),\partial h(x)) \to 0$ [then](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436980/99469) $x_n \to x$. This implies $g$ is continuous w.r.t. the subspace topology of $D$. Hence $g$ is Borel measurable w.r.t. the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(D)$ induced from the subspace topology of $D$. It's **not** necessarily true that $D \in \mathcal B(X)$.

Now we assume $f: S\to X$ is Borel measurable for some $S \in \mathcal B(X)$ such that $f(S) \subset D$. I would like to prove that

> **Theorem** $g \circ f:S \to X$ is Borel measurable.

Could you confirm if my above understanding and below proof are fine?

---

**My attempt** Fix $A \in \mathcal B(X)$. Then $(g \circ f)^{-1} (A) = f^{-1} (g^{-1} (A))$. We have $C := g^{-1} (A) \in \mathcal B (D)$. It suffices to prove that $f^{-1} (C) \in \mathcal B(X)$. There is $C' \in \mathcal B(X)$ such that $C = C' \cap D$. Then
$$
f^{-1} (C) = f^{-1} (C' \cap D) = f^{-1} (C') \cap f^{-1} (D) = f^{-1} (C') \cap S = f^{-1} (C') \in \mathcal B(S).
$$

This completes the proof.