# If $x_n \to x$ then $d_H(\partial h(x_n),\partial h(x)) \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, hausdorff-distance

Let $X := \mathbb R^d$ and $h: X \to \mathbb R$ be convex. Then

- $h$ [is locally Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1336227/1019043), and
- $\partial h (x)$ [is non-empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477191/continuous-convex-function-on-a-normed-vector-space-has-non-empty-subdifferentia), [convex, and compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478500/assume-a-is-open-convex-and-f-convex-continuous-then-f-is-l-lipschitz-o) for all $x \in X$.

Let $d_H$ be the [Hausdorff distance](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hausdorff_distance#Definition) on the collection of compact subsets of $X$. We have

> [Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436895/optimal-transport-how-is-this-transport-map-borel-measurable/436980#436980) Let $h$ be strictly convex. If $x_n, x \in X$ and $d_H(\partial h(x_n),\partial h(x)) \to 0$, then $x_n \to x$.

I would like to ask if the following converse is true, i.e.,

> If $x_n, x \in X$ and $x_n \to x$, then $d_H(\partial h(x_n),\partial h(x)) \to 0$.

I tried to prove it, but failed in the second case below.

---

**My attempt** WLOG we assume there is $r>0$ such that $(x_n) \subset B(x, r)$. There is $L>0$ such that $h$ is $L$-Lipschitz on $B(x, r)$. By [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478500/assume-a-is-open-convex-and-f-convex-continuous-then-f-is-l-lipschitz-o), we get
$$
\bigcup_{y \in B(x,r)} \partial h(y) \subset B(0, L).
$$

Let $A_n := \partial h(x_n)$ and $A := \partial h(x)$. We need to prove that $d_H (A_n, A) \to 0$. Assume the contrary that $d_H (A_n, A) \not\to 0$. WLOG, there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $d_H (A_n, A) \ge \varepsilon$ for all $n$. By definition of $d_H$, we have $2$ cases.

1. WLOG, there exist $p_n \in A_n$ such that $d (p_n, A) \ge \varepsilon$ for all $n$.  Then $|p_n|\le L$ for all $n$. Wlog, we assume $p_n \to p$ for some $p \in X$. For all $y\in X$,
   $$
   \begin{align}
   h(y) - h(x_n) &\ge \langle p_n, y-x_n \rangle \\
   &= \langle p_n, y-x \rangle + \langle p_n, x-x_n \rangle \\
   &\ge \langle p_n, y-x \rangle -  L |x-x_n|.
   \end{align}
   $$
   Taking the limit, we get $h(y)-h(x) \ge \langle p, y-x \rangle$ for all $y\in X$. This implies $p \in A$ and thus $d(p_n, A) \to 0$. This is a contradiction.
2. WLOG, there exist $p_n \in A$ such that $d (p_n, A_n) \ge \varepsilon$ for all $n$. Wlog, we assume $p_n \to p$ for some $p\in A$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that
   $$
   |p-y| \ge \varepsilon/2 \quad \forall y \in \bigcup_{n \ge N} A_n.
   $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @IosifPinelis in [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436895/optimal-transport-how-is-this-transport-map-borel-measurable/436980?noredirect=1#comment1126564_436980), the converse is not true. A counter example is $d=1$ and $h(x) := |x| + x^2$.

---

We have $h'(x) = 2x+1$ if $x>0$ and $2x-1$ if $x<0$. We have $h'_+ (0)=1$ and $h'_-(0)=-1$. So $h$ is not differentiable at $0$. We have
$$
\partial h (0) = \{p \in \mathbb R : x^2 + |x| \ge p x \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb R\}.
$$

Clearly, if $|p| \le 1$ then $p \in \partial h (0)$. As such, $\partial h (0)$ contains at least two elements. On the other hand, $\partial h (x)$ is a singleton for all $x \neq 0$. If $x_n \neq 0$ and $x_n \to 0$, we never have  $\partial h (x_n) \to \partial h (0)$ in $d_H$.